# Ajax form sending null data to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am trying to send the form data to PHP with AJAX but when dumping data on PHP page it is returning null values.

Actually, I want a program where I can upload an image than in pop up crop it and then save the cropped image in the database.

My code is given below:

```js
$('#fileinput').on('change', function() {
  var formD = new FormData();
  var file = $('#fileinput')[0].files[0];
  // var nfile = file.serializeArray();
  // console.log(file);
  formD.append('file', file);
  formD.append("clientID", 2993);
  console.log(formD);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'croped.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      'ff': formD
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: true,
    // dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image" id="fileinput" />
  <input type="submit" name="upld" id="upldbtn" />
</form>
```

**croped.php**

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
echo "ll";
?>
```

Please let me know what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: this is the wrong way of uploading file using ajax

Comment: apply bewlo code it may help you and use <?php

    var_dump($_FILES);
    echo "ll";
?>

Comment: FormData prepares a _complete_ form data submission set, including all parameter names, values etc. already. You are invalidating that data structure by trying to send it “as” a specific parameter named `ff`. You need to send this FormData object, and nothing else: `data: formData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it works for me :)

1. contentType: false,
2. data: formD,

For example

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "croped.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formD,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    // dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
  });
```

For the php code

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data" 
        id="formdata">
        <input type = "file" name = "image" id="fileinput" />
        <input type = "submit" name="upld" id="upldbtn" />
   </form>

$("#formdata").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();    
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
});
```

Comment: No this also is not working for me. this is giving this result in formData:FormData {}__proto__: FormDataappend: ƒ append()delete: ƒ delete()entries: ƒ entries()forEach: ƒ forEach()get: ƒ ()getAll: ƒ getAll()has: ƒ has()keys: ƒ keys()arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 0name: "keys"__proto__: ƒ ()[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]set: ƒ ()values: ƒ values()constructor: ƒ FormData()Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ entries()Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "FormData"__proto__: Object

And on the php page : array(0) {
}

Please suggest

Comment: i think you missing something

Comment: Now I am facing problem given in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56576558/jcrop-cropped-image-save-to-database?noredirect=1#comment99734196_56576558